# sub soil data finding

Tags: soil, soil-science

I am going to search  and finding some subsoil data, (vanGenuchten Parameters, specific storage, Hydraulic conductivity, porosity, Manning coefficient and humidity of root zone) I have no idea about it and want to know if there any sites about this data that one can downloaded them? is there any other way or guide? maybe someone have same problem like me and know about tips that are helping.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The United States Geological survey might have some data on soil
As should the US Dept of Agriculture.
More to it, Universities with Agriculture departments